# Can a boolean expression be evaluated using its corresponding BDD (Binary Decision Diagram) in BuDDy?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, binary-decision-diagram

I am very new to BuDDy (http://buddy.sourceforge.net/manual/main.html), and I'm in a context where I have to evaluate a boolean expression based on its corresponding BDD.

Let's assume the expression looks like this: `(!a && b)`. I want to be able to set the truth values for `a` and `b` and evaluate the entire formula using the BDD.

Is this possible by any means in BuDDy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bdd_retrict(formula, valuation)` where formula is the BDD representing the expression you want to evaluate, and `valuation` is a BDD representing a conjunction of variables such as `a & !b` (if you want to set `a` to true, and `!b` to false).  This will return a new formula with all variables in `valuation` replaced by their value. So if `valuation` covers all variables in `formula`, the result will be either `bddtrue` or `bddfalse`.